# Unexpected TableView cell white color separator in iOS greater than 9.0

Tags: ios, ios10, uitableview

I have a table view (XIB, no Autolayout) with Custom cell (XIB, no Autolayout).

Problem is, in iOS=>9.0 when scrolling or highlighting(by long press) table Cell 
showing white border. Sometimes upper/bottom line sometimes both.

```
SeparatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
```

I have done some R&D. Its not table's background or viewcontroller's background color or not even cell 's background color.

[image: Single separator]

[image: Both separator]

Comment: Check in device, you won't get that separator. Or else try with full screen of simulator, then also you won't get those separators.

Comment: It's not simulator issue. I experienced this in device, then test in simulator. Same result.

Comment: any luck? having this issue in ios12

Answer (score 0):

Many times I have seen this kind of separator, while running my application in simulator and when not running in Full screen. I can see you are also checking in Simulator and I guess your simulator not in its original size (The simulator we get when press Command + 1, is treated as Original size here)

Check in device, you won't get that separator. Or you can also try with full screen of simulator, then also you won't get those separators.

Hope it helps...

Comment: It's not simulator issue. I experienced this in device, then test in simulator. Same result.